# pass Jenkins workspace changes to dir in /var/www

Tags: jenkins

I dont finish to understand. Jenkins is working well but my dir in /var/www is not up to date. But in workspace of jenkins proyect shows is up to date. How to pass changes from workspace to /var/www/myproject.

When I make a commit, it is pulling from jenkins workspace but my web directory no, how do I make to have up to date this directory.

Comment: Jenkins builds the project within the `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace` directory with each project having its own separate folder. What you are observing is expected. Are you building something in Jenkins and want to copy the artifact or files to your web directory /var/www ?

Comment: You need some sort of shell script to update your /var/www folder.

If you're building the project on the same machine as your webserver, you could just do some kind of cp command from workspace > /var/www. 

If you're uploading a deployment artifact / package to your webserver, you need to open it up and copy the relevant files into your /var/www folder. 

The 'workspace' is just the designated area for jenkins to store your project files.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add new execute shell in jenkins to copy from Jenkins workspace to folder you want.

```
cp -a /path/from /path/to
```

For exampe

```
cp -a /pathToJenkinsWorksapcefolder /var/www
```

For Windows you can use execute windows batch command in jenkins

```
xcopy d:\pathToJenkinsWorksapcefolder d:\var\www\ /e
```

Comment: @EngrUmair in my case it is in /home/{user}/.jenkins/workspace

Answer (score 0):

u can copy files from the workspace like this

```
stage {
  // to copy mydir and myfile from the current workspace
  sh ”””
    cp -ar mydir /var/www
    cp myfike /var/www
  ”””
}
```